# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I previously had tensorflow with gpu support installed and working. I tried to install keras afterwhich nothing would work anymore. I have since uninstalled keras and tensorflow.

I tried re-installing tensorfow with gpu support (now version 1.9) following the instructions on the tensorflow webpage https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux (I am running ubuntu 18 by the way). I tried running the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

and I get the error

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-25b92e4d5dec>", line 2, in <module>
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

I tried looking at other threads and there was a suggestion to capitalize the C in 'constant' but that didnt work either.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Is your script named "tensorflow.py"?

Comment: no it is temp.py*

Comment: Is there a different script in the same directory called "tensorflow.py"?

Comment: Not that I can clearly see, unfortunately. I will continue to look though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your installation is corrupted, doing the following should enable you to be back on track.

Could you try the following:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv

## Linux:
source venv/bin/activate

## Windows:
venv\Scripts\activate.bat

pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0

python temp.py
```

If this works without any problem. Your python installation is corrupted, I recommend you to manually delete everything in your python librairies.

Maybe this will help:

1. Open a new terminal
2. `pip uninstall tensorflow -y`
3. `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu -y`
4. `pip uninstall tensorboard -y`
5. `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0 -y`

**If you already use a virtualenv, just delete the folder and recreate it**.

Comment: Thank you. Before I read this I uninstall anaconda and tensorflow and have reinstalled them. Now I have the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. But I think that is because I need to put a line of code into bash.rc.  If this works I will give you the answer

Comment: My comment is still valid, try to use a virtualenv

Comment: I am working on following your instructions now -- that worked

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue and I mistakenly named my file as `tensorflow.py`. Same issue would occur if folder name is tensorflow.

I just renamed file with something else and it resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

just do different  "tensorflow.py" very important

Comment: Aah, that was it. I named my files "pytorch.py" and "tensorflow.py" when testing the two. After renaming "tensorflow.py" to "test-tensorflow.py", it executed fine.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create new virtualenv

> How to create virtuealenv (https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

2. pip3 install requests
3. pip3 install -q -U tensor2tensor
4. pip3 install tensorflow

For some reason the dependencies of the tensorflow remain in the system, so creating from scratch can solve the problem.

Comment: I recommend to rephrase a little (actually more of deleting parts). You want to avoid the impression (even only at first glance) that this is a "Me tool." post.